# Perguntas com Checkbox dinâmico com required ou não

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

Olá, já tentei de tudo com javascript, de tutoriais que encontrei na internet, mas nada me ajuda, acho que é porque meu form é dinâmico, ou seja, o usuário que cadastra as perguntas e alternativas. 
No caso assim, esse código pega do banco duas tabelas, uma com a pergunta (nela salva, se a pergunta é obrigatória ou não) e no outro, salva as alternativas (titulo e id). o problema é como faço para deixar os checkboxers obrigatórios? tipo, só os que no banco estiverem com o obrigatório= 1, e também, todas as alternativas, tem que ser com ids dinâmicos, como mostra o código,  alguém que manje de JS e PHP pode dar uma luz? Obrigado!

**Edit: Se a pergunta for obrigatória, o usuário tem que selecionar pelo menos um campo, senão não for obrigatória, não precisa selecionar nada.**

```
<form action="envia.php" method="post" class="ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-cross" autocomplete="off">
    <?php
        $i = 1;
        $i2 = 1;
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM perguntas WHERE type = '3' ";
        $rs2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        while($dados2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs2)){
    ?>
    <section>
            <h2 style="font-size:3.0em"><?php echo $dados2['title']?></h2>
            <?php 
            if(!empty($dados2['imagem'])){ 
                echo '<img src="adm/perguntas/'.$dados2['imagem'].'" width="100%" />';
            };
            ?>
            <div class="ac-custom" >
                <ul>
                    <?php
                        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM alternativas WHERE id_de = ".$dados2['id']." ";
                        $rs3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
                        while($dados3 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs3)){
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <input id="cb<?php echo $i++?>" value="<?php echo $dados3['alternativa']?>" name="cb<?php echo $dados3['id']?>" type="checkbox" required>
                        <label for="cb<?php echo $i2++?>" style="font-size:2.0em"><?php echo $dados3['alternativa']?></label>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </section>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <div class="ac-custom" style="text-align:center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: O que você quis dizer `tem que ser com ids dinâmicos`? Seria algo como `cb + a id da alternativa na tabela` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por passos.

Primeiramente você deve verificar se a pergunta é obrigatória, para isso dentro do `while($dados2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs2))` crie uma variável ex:

```
$obrigatorio = "";
```

Abaixo da variável criada, crie uma condição `if` que ira verificar se a pergunta é obrigatória, ex:

```
if ($dados2['obrigatorio']) { // 1 = true
    $obrigatorio = ' required'; // Obrigatório
} else { // 0 = false
    $obrigatorio = ''; // Não é obrigatório
}
```

Segundo, você deve imprimir a variável `$obrigatorio` na tela, então na linha

```
<input id="cb<?php echo $i++?>" value="<?php echo $dados3['alternativa']?>" name="cb<?php echo $dados3['id']?>" type="checkbox" required>
```

Altere `required` para `<?php echo $obrigatorio; ?>`, ficando assim:

```
<input id="cb<?php echo $i++; ?>" value="<?php echo $dados3['alternativa']; ?>" name="cb<?php echo $dados3['id']; ?>" type="checkbox"<?php echo $obrigatorio; // Retorna se o campo é obrigatório ?>>
```